# How to add a checkbox control to an Excel cell programatically or check or uncheck an existing checkbox

Tags: c#, visual-studio, office-interop, excel-interop, office-automation

I am using the Excel COM object in C# and want to insert a checkbox dynamically to an Excel sheet and make it checked or unchecked based on a condition.

OR

how can i mark as checked an existing checkbox  in the Excel sheet programatically. 
 I have looked around and I didn't find any solution.

Answer (score 3):

You can always record a macro in MS Excel and it will give you a good idea of what needs to be done with Excel object in order to achieve something. For example, when recording macro for your problem, it came out with the following code:

```
ActiveSheet.OLEObjects.Add(ClassType:="Forms.CheckBox.1", Link:=False, _
        DisplayAsIcon:=False, Left:=65.25, Top:=24, Width:=108, Height:=21). _
        Select
```

I hope that from here you can see what needs to be done to insert checkbox on the active sheet.

Here is more detailed explanation (Visual Studio 2010 and C#):
1. Fire up Visual Studio and create new project (windows app or console app)
2. Right click on References and select "Add Reference"
3. Select COM references and add Microsoft Excel xx.x Object Library (in my case xx.x is 14.0 which is Excel 2010).
4. Somewhere in your code (some function like Main or some click on a button) add this code:

```
// Start excel
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application oXL = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
oXL.Visible = true;

// Get a sheet 
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Workbook oWB = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Workbook)oXL.Workbooks.Add(System.Reflection.Missing.Value);
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet oSheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet)oWB.ActiveSheet;

// Get ole objects and add new one
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.OLEObjects objs = oSheet.OLEObjects();

// Here is the method that is posted in the answer
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.OLEObject obj = objs.Add("Forms.CheckBox.1", 
    System.Reflection.Missing.Value,
    System.Reflection.Missing.Value,
    false,
    false,
    System.Reflection.Missing.Value,
    System.Reflection.Missing.Value,
    65.25,
    24,
    108,
    21);
// Here, you are making it checked. obj.Object is dynamic, so you will not get help from visual studio, but you know what properties CheckBox can have, right?
obj.Object.Value = true;
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you @vucetica for you answer, but how can i achieve this in C# since the Macro is a VB code???

Comment: is there any way to mark as checked an existing checkbox in an excel sheet?

Comment: I thought that you already had some code where you are doing Excel automation. That would probably be another question and you can find many resources online, starting from msdn: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/302084 I haven't tried to place checkbox on an excel spreadseet, but once you get "ActiveSheet" object, you will see that it is quite easy to convert this VBA code into C# calls because from VBA code you see what methods need to be called and with which parameters (COM components have the same interface no matter from which language you are using them).

Comment: how can i convert the VBA generated code to C# though?, i have tried online converters but didn't succeed.

Comment: Hi Vucetica, can you give me idea on how to convert the above code to c#?   (ActiveSheet.OLEObjects.Add(ClassType:="Forms.CheckBox.1", Link:=False, _
        DisplayAsIcon:=False, Left:=65.25, Top:=24, Width:=108, Height:=21). _
        Select)

Comment: take a look at the updated answer, I've put more detailed instructions on how this can be achieved. I hope that you can continue from here and that this answers your question. Still, you can learn what can/should be done in office automation just by looking at recorded macros.

Comment: Hi Vucetica, i really appreciate for getting back to me. I have tried to put the code you provided me to the method i defined to write to EXCEL, but it's giving me errors message ("No overload for method 'OLEObjects' takes '0'") at /Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.OLEObjects objs = oSheet.OLEObjects(???);/. The thing is i am working on .net web application, will that be the case or what object am i suppose to pass to the OLEObjects() method? , many thanks for reaching for me!

Comment: You will need Excel installed on that server. Also, methods can vary a bit depending on installed office version. I've tried with office 2010.

Comment: Hi Vucetica, i have tried the above code by creating a new windows application and putting the code inside onclick even of a button and added the office and excel references.But it's not working, it giving me the same error-No overload for method 'OLEObjects' takes '0'-. excel is already installed on the development server and i am able to write to excel using the method i defined, i am just having hard time to insert a checkbox. I am using Visual studio 2008. Please help me if you can get a chance. Many Thanks!

Comment: Here is the code: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/3214181/Excel.zip Please note that it is .NET 4.0

Comment: Hi Vucetica many thanks, finally the error is gone after i passed System.Refelection.Missing.Value when calling the OLEobjects() method. I have three issues now: (1)the line obj.Object.Value = true; saying Object doesn't contain a definition for 'Value'  i.e. to mark the checkbox as checked (2) is there any way i can insert the checkbox by specifying a cell column and row ? rather than using coordinate values ? (3) how can i either add the checkbox with out it's name (like "CheckBox1") or  change the checkbox name to something else. many thanks for your continued support!!

Comment: (1) great (2) don't know (3) Not sure, but look at my code, like you set obj.Object.Value = true; at the end, try also setting obj.Object.Caption = "my new caption" as well as many other properties. To see what properties are available to you, open one empty spreadsheet, place one checkbox on it, right click, properties and you will see plenty of them. I'm signing off now from this question, because this went far beyond question itself. Perhaps you can upvote or accept the answer if you found it useful.

Comment: @AleksandarVucetic code works great! thanks for the tutorial.